# What technique would I use to translate any GPS coordinate to a grid?

Tags: gps, convert

If I wanted to divide the existing GPS coordinate system (lat,long) into a "grid" - effectively reducing its resolution - are there any established techniques, formulas or gotchas that I might benefit from knowing about to ensure I'm always translating coordinates to the same grid?

Example:

- `0.0000000,0.0000000` maps to cell `0,0`
- `0.0686645,0.8047485` maps to cell `1,0`

My assumption is that my only input would be a desired size for each cell and likely the assumption that the grid will always originate from the same point (as my example above implies, let's say `0.000000,0.000000`).

Moreover, is there a way to do this without having to perform lookups against a large table of cells mapped to GPS coordinate ranges?  Ideally I'd like to be able to just take a latitude and longitude, run it through a formula and know what cell it is within.

Apologies for the very beginner nature of this question.

Comment: Do you want to define the grid size and dimensions yourself? If not, there are quite a few "grids" already created that cover the planet and are ready for you to use, they're called "coordinate systems" in GIS. It sounds like the UTM grid should do what you need, though this is a very broad question and there are lots of possible answers.

Comment: Yeah, I'd like to be able to constrain the size of each grid cell to be as close to 1km squared as possible.  I'm open to it being a bit fuzzy if that's a limitation of any system.

Comment: So basically you just want low precision in your coordinates?

Comment: Yeah as well as the ability to map a high precision coordinate to a low precision one.

Comment: @Omega, if you provide us with more information on how you plan to use this, then we can help you. We would need specifics: what software will you be using; what format the data will be in; et cetera.

Comment: Good overview here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grid_%28spatial_index%29

Comment: @Tom - My software will be a server-side programming language with a postgres database.  I'll be receiving periodic calls from devices informing me of their location.  I just want to convert those coordinates to their lower resolution cell and then store it to match against later.  Ideally I wouldn't have to touch the database until I store the data - the most important thing is that I should be able to do it for any lat/long at any time.